# How can I get the current viewcontroller in awakeFromNib method in the same class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

Please anyone help me to find out a solution for getting the current viewController instance in the `awakeFromNib` method. I think the `awakeFromNib` method is only execute after the initialisation of the viewContoller and it's subviews.

Is there any method to get the viewController instance?

Answer (score -1):

I don't get the question. The view controller is just `self` if you are overriding the `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: I am integrating a slider menu. In the example, which viewcontroller is left and which one is contentviewcontroller is  set in the rootviewcontroller. Then actually I want to set these properties in the same viewcontroller.